# Photoshop CS6 white around transparent image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

When I save for web or save my PSD in general to make it a PNG, when I upload it to my computer desktop background or into movvie maker, it has a white background around it.

Screenshots:

Before Save: http://prntscr.com/6tfmuk

After Save/Convert to PNG: http://prntscr.com/6tfm8r

Any suggestions?

Comment: Save as PNG24 with **no** matte color.

Comment: Whenever I select PNG24 with interlacing and transparenct, the dialog box is grayed out and will not allow me to select no  matte.

Comment: You don't need interlacing. Just File > Save for Web and choose PNG24

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: Well, that's not very descriptive. Not sure how anyone could help then.

Comment: The white background was still there, due to it being a desktop image, how stupid of me. The Save for Web solution had already been applied, and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop Wallpapers can't have transparent backgrounds. They need solid images or they'll insert white as you stated in your question.

Same for the video editing software. They use black color as a background by default. You must have some layers to see your transparent image.